# (1400, 'GetClassName', 'Invalid window handle.') when using swspotify

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify

I am maker a currently playign kinda thing but the problem is im trying to update the currently playing song every few seconds but it keeps saying '(1400, 'GetClassName', 'Invalid window handle.')' whenever it updates

```
from SwSpotify import spotify
from plyer import notification
import time
from watchpoints import watch
song = spotify.song()
artist = spotify.artist()
message = ''
message_check = message
loop = True
title = 'Currently Playing'
def notif():
    message= '%s by %s' % (song,artist)
    notification.notify(title= title,message= message,app_icon = None,timeout= 10,toast=False)
    print('notif sent')
while True:
    song = spotify.song()
    artist = spotify.artist()
    print (message + '1')
    print (message_check + '2')
    message= '%s by %s' % (song,artist)
    if message != message_check:
        notif()
        message_check = message
        continue
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

Comment: You don't need to write `continue`, loops automatically continue unless the `while` condition fails or you use `break`. `continue` is only needed when you want to start the next iteration before you reach the end of the body.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Your code never calls `GetClassName()`, so it's not clear where this is happening.

Comment: @barmar i used continue cause the loop would fail and wouldnt rerun without it

Comment: Exception has occurred: error
(1400, 'GetClassName', 'Invalid window handle.')
  File "C:\Users\hyper\Documents\better spotify\gui.py", line 17, in <module>
    artist = spotify.artist()

Comment: Which song are you trying to get the artist of there?

Comment: it gets teh artist off the current playign song

Comment: no its not spotipy

Comment: i should add that the first run is perfectly fine its the second run of the loop that it fails

Comment: This seems like a bug in SwSpotify, not a problem with your code. It's not catching exceptions when it searches for the Spotify window.

Comment: alr i might just have to run tehj script over and over from another script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so turns out it was the notification timeout that was causing the request to fail i changed the notification extension and everything is workign perfectly

```
from SwSpotify import spotify
from SwSpotify import *
from notify import notification
song = ''
artist = ''
import time
message_check = ''
title = 'Currently Playing On Spotify'
while True:
    try:
        song, artist = spotify.current()
        af = '%s by %s' % (song,artist)
        print(af)
        if message_check != af:
            message_check = af
            notification(af, title='Currently Playing')
            continue
        else:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            continue
        time.sleep(5)       
    except SpotifyNotRunning as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

SwSpotify isn't catching exceptions when it uses `win32gui.enumWindows`. You can add your own exception handling around the calls.

You can also use `spotify.current()` to get both the song and artist at once.

I also don't see any reason for getting the song and artist before the loop, since the loop overwrites them immediately.

```
from SwSpotify import spotify
from plyer import notification
import time
from watchpoints import watch

message = ''
message_check = message
loop = True
title = 'Currently Playing'
def notif():
    message= '%s by %s' % (song,artist)
    notification.notify(title= title,message= message,app_icon = None,timeout= 10,toast=False)
    print('notif sent')
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            song, artist = spotify.current()
        except:
            time.sleep(1)
    print (message + '1')
    print (message_check + '2')
    message= '%s by %s' % (song,artist)
    if message != message_check:
        notif()
        message_check = message
        continue
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

Comment: for soem reason this isn t working no error code but it isnt working

Comment: Then the bug is more serious than I thought. You should report it to the library developer.